# PROBLEMAS CON NO-IP

Tags: angular, servidor, redes

Tengo alojada en un servidor, una base de datos que necesito consultar desde una aplicación web, el problema es que mi servidor recibe señal de un `router` y este a su vez la recibe de `2 modem's` lo cual causa un caos a la hora de la dirección IP publica, intente conectarme mediante `no-ip` sin embargo siempre rechaza la conexión y me dice que no se puede conectar con `midominio.ddns.ip`

Comment: Te recomiendo desarrollar un poco la pregúnta, ser un poco más específico y compartir algo de código que hayas utilizado para intentar resolver tu problema. Revisa este enlace para que tus preguntas tengan mayor aceptación: (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

te comento
La base de datos puedes tenerla alojada en una "maquina x", e independientemente de dónde reciba su conexión a internet, siempre tendrá una ip, que dependiendo de tu modem o router, puede ser ip compartida, hablando específicamente de la ip pública, ya que la local, no se puede compartir. Ahora, no conozco tu problema a detalle y tampoco especificas que base de datos utilizas, pero puedes intentar todos estos pasos.

1.- Reinicia todos los servicios asociados a tu servidor de base de datos y/o valida que todos estén activos, por ejemplo si fuera sql, puedes ejecutar services.msc y ver que todos los servicios que inicien con sql estén ejecutándose, hay directivas que no permiten que se acceda desde afuera si no están activados, por ejemplo el SQL Browser.

2.- Abre tus puertos locales, en el firewall, por ejemplo el 70100; o algo similar.

3.- revisa que la computadora desde la que quieres acceder se encuentre en la misma red. y apunta a server_name=ip_local:70100;

4.- Si quieres acceder desde fuera de la red, es necesario que abras también los puertos del modem, apuntando a la ip pública y local y accederias a server_name=ip_publica:70100;

No-ip te permite enmascarar tu ip con un dns, sin embargo esto no quiere decir que no tengas que abrir tus puertos, tendrías que validar que si tu dns de no-ip apunta a tu ip local,que en la página de configuración del modem tengas abierto algún puerto apuntando a esa ip local y su fuera a la ip pública igual.